# forward revert message from low level solidity call

Tags: solidity, revert-opcode, proxy-contracts

I'm working on a proxy contract that will perform calls as follows:

```
bool success;
bytes memory returndata;
(success, returndata) = _to.call.value(_value)(_data);
require(success);
```

this works great, except that, if the call reverts with an error message, this function will simply reverts, hiding the reason string.

How can I retrieve the reason string (I assume in the returndata) and use if to revert properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it very concisely:

```solidity
(bool success, bytes memory result) = addr.delegatecall(data);
if (success == false) {
    assembly {
      revert(add(result,32),mload(result))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The following code performs a delegate call, and if the delegate call reverts, the transaction is reverted with the reason given by the delegate call.

```solidity
(bool success, bytes memory result) = address(_impl).delegatecall(signature);
if (success == false) {
    assembly {
        let ptr := mload(0x40)
        let size := returndatasize()
        returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)
        revert(ptr, size)
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: with solidity 0.5.5

Comment: Thanks, work with solc 0.7 ! *`returndatasize()`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

It is simpler than you think:

```
require(success, string (returndata));
```

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/units-and-global-variables.html#error-handling) for details.  You may also forward raw bytes, but you will need to use assembly.

Comment: I tryed `require(success, returndata);` and started looking into assembly when it failled to compile ... thanks for proving how stupid I am :P

Comment: I get `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revertï¿½yï¿½ )ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token -- Reason given:y )ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token.` There may be a encoding error, maybe removing the 32 first bytes (the length of returndata)? (with solidity 0.5.5)

Comment: Incorrect answer, `string (returndata)` returns the empty string if `success` is `false`. See the correct answer by @Thykof.